# On clicking I'm feeling lucky button, a redirect notice is opened instead of bypassing it

Tags: html, web-frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <form  action="https://google.com/search">
       <input id="a" type="text" name="q" >
       <input class="b" type="submit" value="Google Search">
       <input class="b" type="submit" name="btnI" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
    </form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

The redirected page url is "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/"

How to bypass this redirected page?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form

```
<input value="AINFCbYAAAAAX5HfwE8zYJocO_KK3l0mnekwpjBwzcPb" name="iflsig" type="hidden">
```

note that you would have to update the value from time to time.